# How change Iterable to ArrayList with filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have code :

```
 @GetMapping("/goal/{id}")
    public String goalInfo(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model) {

        if (!goalRepository.existsById(id)) {
            return "redirect:/goal";
        }

        Iterable<SubGoal> subGoal = subGoalRepository.findAll();
        ArrayList<SubGoal> subGoals = new ArrayList<>();

        //How refactor this?
        for(SubGoal sub : subGoal){
            if(sub.getParentGoal().getId().equals(id)){
                subGoals.add(sub);
            }
        }

        if(subGoals.size() > 0) {
            goalPercent(id, subGoal);
        }

        Optional<Goal> goal = goalRepository.findById(id);
        ArrayList<Goal> result = new ArrayList<>();
        goal.ifPresent(result::add);


        model.addAttribute("goal", result);
        model.addAttribute("subGoal",subGoals);
        return "goal/goal-info";
    }
```

Here I get sub-goals from the repository and filter these values.

How I can do it without foreach? I want to use Streams or something else.

Comment: try subGoal.stream().filter(goal-> goal.getParentGoal().getId().equals(id)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))

Comment: The correct answer is _don't do this in the first place_. Any time you're filtering data, you should do so as close to the source as possible to reduce the amount of unnecessary processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert `Iterable` to `Stream` use `StreamSupport.stream(iter.spliterator(), par)`.

```java
Iterable<SubGoal> subGoal = subGoalRepository.findAll();

List<SubGoal> subGoals = StreamSupport
  .stream(subGoal.spliterator(), false)
  .filter(sub -> sub.getParentGoal().getId().equals(id))
  .collect(toList())  // static import `Collectors.toList()`

...
```

Additionally, this part can be also single statement.

**before (three statement)**

```java
Optional<Goal> goal = goalRepository.findById(id);
ArrayList<Goal> result = new ArrayList<>();
goal.ifPresent(result::add);
```

**after (single statement)**

```java
List<Goal> result = goalRepository.findById(id)
  .map(goal -> singletonList(goal)) // Collections.singletonList()
  .orElse(emptyList());             // Collections.emptyList()
```

#### Updates

**1. `singletonList()`, `emptyList()`**
These are just factory methods used when creating single entity list and empty list.
you can change this part any kind of function that has `Goal` as input and  `List` as output and any empty list.
For example,

```java
.map(goal -> Arrays.asList(goal)) 
.orElse(new ArrayList<>());

or 

.map(goal -> { 
  ArrayList<Goal> l = new ArrayList<>(); 
  l.add(goal);
  return l;
})
...
```

**2. I changed the List Type to `List<Goal>`, not `ArrayList<Goal>`**
Sorry, I missed explanation about that.
In OOP, using **Interface** will be better practices than using **Concrete Class** in many situation.

If you have to use `ArrayList<>` Type explicitly or want to specify actual list instance in some reason, you can also use `toCollection()` like below.

```java
.collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new)) // you can specify the actual list instance
```

Thanks to @John Bollinger @hfontanez for pointing this out.

Comment: I think you mean `Collectors.toList()`, not `Collections.toList()`.  However, that collects to a `List`, not necessarily an `ArrayList`, and the OP specifically asked for the latter.

Comment: The first example is still incorrect in that it attempts to assign a `List<SubGoal>` to a variable of type `ArrayList<SubGoal>`.

Comment: Also, `Collections.emptyList()` yields an immutable `List` that (therefore) definitely is not an `ArrayList`.  Although that *might* serve the OP's purposes, it also might fail them badly.

Comment: It's work! Thank you! Can you explain to me how the last piece of code works? What do we use a singleton for?

Comment: @JohnBollinger even though the OP indicated the use of `ArrayList` specifically, this could also be used as a learning opportunity that it is better to code to interfaces rather than to concretions. You and I know that insisting in using specific concretions is often a mistake in itself.

Comment: @hfontanez, I certainly agree that it is better to code to interfaces, and that insisting on specific concretions is often a mistake.  That would be a worthy topic for this answer to address.  But this answer produces objects of different type than requested without commenting on that or discussing the issues involved, and that's a situation that would bear improvement.

Comment: I'd updated my answer, i missed explanation about that, 
Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare an iterable on your code to filter your ArrayList. The filter method already provides one for you. You can use:

```
subGoals = subGoals.stream().filter(subGoal ->
 /*Here goes your filter condition*/ ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: this will give a list. However, you can do something like .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)) to return arrayLst

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: As @Shubham said, instead of returning an ArrayList, the `.collect(Collectors.toList())` return an abstract List, but it can be assigned to an existing ArrayList without problems considering the polymorphism concept that one inherited class can assume the superclass value, but not the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

This is *client-side filtering* and is extremely inefficient. Instead, simply declare this method on your repository interface:

```java
Collection<SubGoal> findByParentId(Long id); // or Stream, Iterable
```